# Merge 2 vectors according their time values

Tags: matlab

I would like to merge 2 vectors according their time values. This should look like this (column 1 = time, column 2 = actual value):

```
A =

           1         234
           3         121
           4         456
           6        6756

B =

           2         435
           5          90
          10         365
```

Result:

```
C =

           1         234
           2         435
           3         121
           4         456
           5          90
           6        6756
          10         365
```

Is there an elegant way to realize this in Matlab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an easy one-liner:

```
C = sortrows([A;B])

C =

      1    234
      2    435
      3    121
      4    456
      5     90
      6   6756
     10    365
```

Note that this assumes that all of the time values in column 1 are unique. If this is not the case, you can use `accumarray`:

```
A =

      1    234
      3    121
      4    456
      6   6756

B =

     2   435
     5    90
    10   365

B = [B; 1 512]
B =

     2   435
     5    90
    10   365
     1   512

C = [A;B];
D = accumarray(C(:,1),C(:,2));
U = unique(C(:,1));
E = [U,D(U)]
E =

      1    746    %// 764 = 234 + 512
      2    435
      3    121
      4    456
      5     90
      6   6756
     10    365
```

Comment: ahhhhhhh, I just remembered this. Nice one!

Comment: @GameOfThrows Yeah, you would expect `sort` to do this, but MATLAB is odd sometimes. You can also get the indices with `sortrows` just like in `sort`, in case you ever need them.

Answer (score 1):

First you want to vertical concatenation:

```
A = [1 234; 3 121; 4 456; 6 6756];
B = [2 435; 5 90; 10 365];
C = vertcat(A,B)
```

Then you want to sort your answer based on the first column:

```
[~,inx]=sort(C(:,1));
out = C(inx,:);

>> out = 
       1         234
       2         435
       3         121
       4         456
       5          90
       6        6756
      10         365
```

So much more difficult than the 1 liner:

```
out = sortrows(C,1)
```

Why Matlab, why don't you have an option in `sort` to keep the index!

Answer (score 1):

First I would merge these matrices and then sort them by first column.

```
C = [A; B]
[Y, I] = sort(C(:,1))
C = C(I,:)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, you will need to do some form of concatenation and sorting. This is a one liner

```
C = sort([A,B],1);
```

Comment: This seems not to produce the desired result even with the correction by @GameOfThrows .

Comment: @mikkola yes, because matlab sort is not something like Java's sort by key, you need to re-index based on the new index, really annoying.