# Mean of two values having the same timestamp in an array

Tags: arrays, matlab

Following my question [Merge 2 vectors according their time values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34747258/merge-2-vectors-according-their-time-values/): If two values in an array have the same timestamp I need to combine them and use the average value. How can I realize this in an elegant way?

Here is an example:

```matlab
%1st column = time; 2nd column = value
%there are two values with timestamp '6'
C = [1,34;2,34;5,68;6,2;6,3;7,45]
C =

     1    34
     2    34
     5    68
     6     2
     6     3
     7    45
%after processing
C_proc =

    1.0000   34.0000
    2.0000   34.0000
    5.0000   68.0000
    6.0000    2.5000
    7.0000   45.0000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what [**`accumarray`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) is for:

```
out = accumarray(C(:,1),C(:,2),[],@mean)  %// use with care, see below
```

If you don't want the zeros for the skipped indices, combine it with [**`unique`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), which also avoids the necessary assumption of integer timestamps of the first approach:

```
[a,~,u] = unique(C(:,1))
out = [a accumarray(u,C(:,2),[],@mean)]
```

---

```
out =

    1.0000   34.0000
    2.0000   34.0000
    5.0000   68.0000
    6.0000    2.5000
    7.0000   45.0000
```